# Tkinter GUI crashed upon trying to resize the window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to build a GUI for an app I am currently working on but I have encountered a weird crash when I try and resize the window.

It seems like python its self is crashing but I am unable to track down the problem. Any help is appreciated.

## Crash Log:

```
2018-01-26 17:20:29.424 Python[7025:727130] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [0 nan]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9f95152b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fffb4027cad objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9f9cfa0d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   QuartzCore                          0x00007fffa54f7980 _ZN2CA5Layer12set_positionERKNS_4Vec2IdEEb + 152
    4   QuartzCore                          0x00007fffa54f7af5 -[CALayer setPosition:] + 44
    5   QuartzCore                          0x00007fffa54f814b -[CALayer setFrame:] + 644
    6   CoreUI                              0x00007fffab2a1112 _ZN20CUICoreThemeRenderer26MakeOrUpdateScrollBarLayerEPK13CUIDescriptoraPP7CALayer + 1284
    7   CoreUI                              0x00007fffab29d317 _ZN20CUICoreThemeRenderer19CreateOrUpdateLayerEPK13CUIDescriptorPP7CALayer + 1755
    8   CoreUI                              0x00007fffab21f4d1 _ZN11CUIRenderer19CreateOrUpdateLayerEPK14__CFDictionaryPP7CALayer + 175
    9   CoreUI                              0x00007fffab222185 CUICreateOrUpdateLayer + 221
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff9df86623 -[NSCompositeAppearance _callCoreUIWithBlock:options:] + 226
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff9d633a9d -[NSAppearance _createOrUpdateLayer:options:] + 76
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff9d8ac143 -[NSScrollerImp _animateToRolloverState] + 274
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff9d86bb79 __49-[NSScrollerImp _installDelayedRolloverAnimation]_block_invoke + 673
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff9d732331 -[NSScrollerImp _doWork:] + 15
    15  Foundation                          0x00007fffa132fc88 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 417
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9f8d0e14 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9f8d0a9f __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1071
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9f8d05fa __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 298
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9f8c8021 __CFRunLoopRun + 2065
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9f8c75b4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    21  Tcl                                 0x0000000108db4b43 Tcl_WaitForEvent + 314
    22  Tcl                                 0x0000000108d845cd Tcl_DoOneEvent + 274
    23  _tkinter.cpython-36m-darwin.so      0x0000000108cfd760 _tkinter_tkapp_mainloop + 252
    24  Python                              0x0000000108703641 _PyCFunction_FastCallDict + 166
    25  Python                              0x0000000108767cde call_function + 489
    26  Python                              0x0000000108760b93 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 4811
    27  Python                              0x0000000108768440 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1719
    28  Python                              0x0000000108768b43 fast_function + 218
    29  Python                              0x0000000108767cb5 call_function + 448
    30  Python                              0x0000000108760b93 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 4811
    31  Python                              0x0000000108768440 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1719
    32  Python                              0x000000010875f84e PyEval_EvalCode + 42
    33  Python                              0x000000010878819e run_mod + 54
    34  Python                              0x00000001087871bf PyRun_FileExFlags + 160
    35  Python                              0x000000010878689c PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 285
    36  Python                              0x000000010879a6c0 Py_Main + 3484
    37  Python                              0x00000001086bee1d Python + 7709
    38  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fffb4905255 start + 1
    39  ???                                 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
Abort trap: 6
```

Here are the relevant python files:

## Main.py:

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
    from tkspellcheck import TextEventMixin, Spellcheck
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
    from tkspellcheck import TextEventMixin, Spellcheck
    from ScrolledText import ScrolledText

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        ## Toolbar
        self.toolbar = tk.Frame()
        self.toolbar.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.status = tk.Label(self.toolbar, width=15, relief=tk.SUNKEN)
        self.status.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.X, expand=1)

        self.text = ExampleText(self, width=80, wrap=tk.WORD, highlightthickness=0) # I Think the problem relates to these two lines
        self.text.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1) #I Think the problem relates to these two lines

    ## From example at https://github.com/bencorman/tkspellcheck
    def update_wordcount(self):
        wc = len(self.text.get('1.0', 'end').split(' '))
        wcount = 'Wordcount: {0}'.format(wc)
        self.status.config(text=wcount)

## From example at https://github.com/bencorman/tkspellcheck
class ExampleText(TextEventMixin, ScrolledText):
    """Adapted from: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/464635
    """
    def __init__(self, root, *args, **kw):
        ScrolledText.__init__(self, root, *args, **kw)
        self.root = root
        self.spellcheck = Spellcheck(self)
        self.spellcheck.spellcheck_enabled = True
        self._init_textevent_mixin()

    def fire_on_textevent(self):
        self.root.update_wordcount()
        self.spellcheck.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app=App()
    app.mainloop()
```

## tkspellcheck.py:

```
## File From https://github.com/bencorman/tkspellcheck
import tk
#from enchant.checker import SpellChecker
#from enchant.tokenize import EmailFilter, URLFilter, HTMLChunker

class TextEventMixin(object):
    """Adds a trigger to the Tkinter Text widget that fires on modification.

    From: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/464635
    """

    def _init_textevent_mixin(self):
        """Call this from the text widget to bind the <<Modified>> event to the
        Callback.
        """
        # Clear the alert flag and set up the _reset_alert_flag attribute.
        self._reset_alert_flag()

        # Bind the <<Modified>> virtual event to the internal callback.
        self.bind('<<Modified>>', self._txtevt)

    def _txtevt(self, evt):
        """Calls the user callback and resets the <<Modified>> event.
        """

        # If this is being called recursively as a result of the call to
        # _reset_alert_flag() below, then we do nothing.
        if not self._resetting_alert_flag:

            # Clear the Tk 'modified' variable.
            self._reset_alert_flag()

             # Call the user-defined callback.
            self.fire_on_textevent()

    def fire_on_textevent(self):
        """Override this method in your class. This is called whenever the
        <<Modified>> event is triggered.
        """
        pass

    def _reset_alert_flag(self):
        """Reset the <<Modified>> event to false so it'll fire again on the next
        modification.

        Setting the Text Widget's modified variable triggers the <<Modified>>
        event which can trigger _txtevt() recursively.

        This uses the _resetting_alert_flag to disable the internal callback
        _txtevt() to avoid this recursive call.
        """

        # Set the flag, disable the internal callback
        self._resetting_alert_flag = True

        # edit_modified() only recently became a valid call?
        # The Tkinter Text modified variable can also be set via:
        # self.tk.call(self._w, 'edit', 'modified', 0)
        # edit_modified() information here:
        # http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/Tkinter.Text-class.html#edit_modified
        self.edit_modified(False)

        # Unset the flag, enable the internal callback
        self._resetting_alert_flag = False

class Spellcheck(object):
    def __init__(self, textwidget, **kw):
        pass
```

Comment: Are you certain above code is the [mcve]?

Comment: In what OS, with what versions has it crashed?

Comment: @Nae In order to reproduce the problem yes, this is the most compact I could get it without other errors. Im running MacOS 10.12 Python 3.6.4.

Comment: It looks to me like there's a lot of code you can remove. Are you saying, for example, that `def _tag_remove` is important in order to reproduce this? For that matters, are you sure `spellcheck.py` is related at all? What if you remove it, and any code that uses it? Does the problem go away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my problem.

In case anyone else encounters a similar problem here is a quick tutorial on how to fix it. This is what worked for me on MacOS 10.12

I found this page on [python.org](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/) that pretty much sums up the problem I was having. In one line it said: *"Do not use the version of tkinter that comes pre-installed"*.

## Quick Summary of what I did:

1. Downloaded and installed python version 3.6.3 from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-363/).
2. Downloaded and installed version 8.5.18.0 of ActiveTcl from [here](https://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads).

**WARNING:** This will remove any and all python3 modules you have globally installed.

For a list of recommended ActiveTcl versions for different MacOS versions see [here](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for adding an answer, please mark it as _the_ answer when possible as well If it solved your problem.